# H264 //RTSP using Android phone

Tags: server, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0, nvidia-jetson

I would like to create a VR so I created a RTSP server to link to my Zedmini. It is working if I use a h265 encoder, but the bad thing is the RTSP only works if I use Iphone7 VLC app or computer window 8 VLC software, my Android phone huawei p7 Onvifer app cannot use this RTSP address at all. I need to use huawei p7 for my project as I am going to create the app and link to this RTSP server.

Based on my checking, Some Android device do not support h265 encoder, so I decided to use h264 and I have been googling a lot for few weeks but became frustrated for not finding a solution to use h264.

This is the code which I amend from test-readme.c------>

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { GMainLoop *loop; GstRTSPServer *server; GstRTSPMountPoints *mounts; GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory;

gst_init (&argc, &argv);

loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

/* create a server instance */ server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();

/* get the mount points for this server, every server has a default object

that be used to map uri mount points to media factories */ mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points (server);
/* make a media factory for a test stream. The default media factory can use

gst-launch syntax to create pipelines.
any launch line works as long as it contains elements named pay%d. Each
element with pay%d names will be a stream */ factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();
//working case for streaming video //gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,"( videotestsrc is-live=1 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");

//working case for external camera //gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,"( v4l2src is-live=1 device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw, width=(int)720, height=(int)480 framerate=30/1 format=I420 ! timeoverlay ! omxh265enc ! rtph265pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");

//working case for JX2 camera //gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,"( nvcamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1, format=I420 ! nvvidconv flip-method=4 !video/x-raw, width=(int)720, height=(int)480 framerate=30/1 format=I420 ! timeoverlay ! omxh265enc ! rtph265pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");

//Fail or not working case for Zed mini camera testing FOR H264 gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,"(v4l2src is-live=1 device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw, width=2560, height=720, framerate=30/1, format=I420 ! nvvidconv !video/x-raw, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, framerate=30/1, format=NV12 ! omxh264enc bitrate=10000000 ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");

//working case for Zed mini camera FOR H265 //gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,"(v4l2src is-live=1 device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw, width=2560, height=720, framerate=30/1, format=I420 ! nvvidconv !video/x-raw, width=(int)720, height=(int)480 framerate=30/1 format=I420 ! timeoverlay ! omxh265enc ! rtph265pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");

gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared (factory, TRUE); /* attach the test factory to the /test url */ gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory (mounts, "/test", factory);

/* don't need the ref to the mapper anymore */ g_object_unref (mounts);

/* attach the server to the default maincontext */ gst_rtsp_server_attach (server, NULL);

/* start serving */ g_print ("stream ready at rtsp://172.16.124.75:8554/test\n"); g_main_loop_run (loop);

return 0; }
```

This code is working on streaming video, JX2 camera, simple USB camera (low end), also zedmini camera but using h265. I need the code to run using h264, there must be some element missed out here or wrong.

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory,"(v4l2src is-live=1 device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw, width=2560, height=720, framerate=30/1, format=I420 ! nvvidconv !video/x-raw, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, framerate=30/1, format=NV12 ! omxh264enc bitrate=10000000 ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");
```